# Javascript mishandling special character †

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, text

Within a `textarea`, I want to identify the position of the last "†" character.

```js
var textField = document.getElementById("main_field"); 

console.log(textField.value.indexOf("†"));
```

```html
<textarea id="main_field">Text † entered by user † †</textarea>
```

And though this works very well here, I get odd results in browser

However, it cannot find the character and returns -1.

I tried to understand the internal respresentation of the character. It is outputted in console as "â€¡", which I find odd.

Comment: but `‡` !== `†`

Comment: Please provide the code that allows to reproduce the issue, i.e. add the relevant HTML, initialisation code (setting `startPos`, `textField`, the content of the text field, ...) and the code that outputs -1 when it supposedly shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see how it works.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("textField1").value.lastIndexOf("†"));
console.log(document.getElementById("textField2").value.lastIndexOf("†"));
```

```html
<textarea id="textField1" value="a†b†c†d"></textarea>
<textarea id="textField2">a†b†c†d</textarea>
```

Now that we have seen this in action, we need to find out what's wrong with your code. First of all, you will need to check whether `textField.value` contains the character you are searching for at all. Next, look at this call in your code:

```
.substring(0, startPos)
```

This is effectively getting a substring starting from the very start up until `startPos`. Judging by the name of `startPos`, it seems that instead of getting the string before `startPos` you wanted to get it from `startPos`.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment that accompanies the down-vote, so I could improve on any shortcomings the answer may have. Thanks!